# Visual Studio Community 2015, BSoD

Tags: windows-10, installation, bsod, event-log, visual-studio-2015

I have Downloaded and installed Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 and as the computer reaches around 80% Installation MY Laptop (ASUS - WIndows 10) Crashes and i get a BSoD error BAD_POOL_HEADER error.

do i need to upload a log from anywhere for someone to be able to resolve this isssue for me?

Comment: I installed it on the weekend on two machines, without any issues. So it is not the software. How much memory you have, and how much free disk space?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx activate special pool in driververifier for 3rd party drivers, when you get new crashes, disable it and share (onedrive links) the new dumps.

Comment: ok i will do this i manged to successfully install the program using the .iso file however 2 components fail to install; the first was the 2015 update and the second I am unsure of as i cant remember.

so the problem i am getting now is when i try to run the program it gives me a new BSoD error.

i will follow your instructions on how to log the errors and and upload the dumps for further support

Comment: OK GUYS for whatever reason it has resolved itself, the only thing i can say i did was a SFC check,

i did this by opening CMD prompt as administrator and running the code sfc /scannow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's been a lot of issue reports with the most recent VS 2015. I'd suggest downloading the entire installation ISO. All of the relevant instructions can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070584/how-to-install-vs2015-community-edition-offline

Basically, visit the Visual studio download site (https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) and select the ISO to download instead of the web installer.

Hope that helps. I have not had this issue myself, so can't give you anything more specific.

Comment: i cant find any links for the .iso file everything is just exe for the online install

Comment: actually got it ill let u know how i go